# Issue with serverless deployment using github actions , error -Invalid "--config" value: Unsupported file extension (expected one of: yml, yaml, json,

Tags: lambda, yaml, github-actions, serverless-framework, cicd

I got stuck in a problem with serverless lambda function deployment using GitHub actions.

I am getting an error as below:

```
"Invalid "--config" value: Unsupported file extension (expected one of: yml, yaml, json, js, ts",
```

**Yml**

```yaml
name: Actions-MicroAig-Dev

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - cicd

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x]
    steps:

    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - name: Install Plugin and Deploy
      uses: serverless/github-action@v3.1
      with:
        args: -c "serverless plugin install --name serverless-offline && serverless deploy"
      env:
        # SERVERLESS_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.SERVERLESS_ACCESS_KEY }}
        # or if using AWS credentials directly
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```

My serverless.yml file at the repository root:

```yaml
service: GoPlanet360-api-MicroAIG 
provider: 
  name: aws 
  runtime: nodejs12.x 
  stage: dev 
  region: us-east-1 
plugins: 
  - serverless-offline 
functions: 
  api: 
    handler: index.handler 
    events: 
      - http: ANY / 
      - http: 'ANY /{proxy+}'
```

Comment: Do you have any `serverless` yaml file on the repository root directory?

Comment: @GuiFalourd Yes I have serverless.yml in root,

Comment: @GuiFalourd  
```
service: GoPlanet360-api-MicroAIG
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1

plugins:
 - serverless-offline

functions:
  api:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY /{proxy+}' 
```
this is the configuration I have for serverless

Comment: Ok. According to the [action documentation](https://github.com/serverless/github-action#usage-with-serverless-plugins), shouldn't you add an `entrypoint` input with the `args` input?